# Difficulty in finding correct regex pattern in Angular 7

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have the following regex pattern which is used to replace:

(reply:reply) -> /reply

code:

```
const reg = new RegExp('\\(reply:([^/]*)\\)');
url = url.replace(reg, '$1');
```

I am looking for a regex pattern to replace:

(reply:reply/alphanumeric) -> /reply/*alphanumeric*

Eg: (reply:reply/5acd456) -> /reply/5acd456

I am new to regex patterns, so finding it difficult to come up with a correct solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `'/'+url.slice(7,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const reg = new RegExp('\\(reply:(.*)\\)');
url = url.replace(reg, '/$1');
```

`[^/]*` This would only match characters upto `/`.

`(.*)\\)` This would capture all characters upto last `)` .

Or you could just use slice `'/'+url.slice(7,-1)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. Can you explain the pattern?